# Error: Compile Error: Unexpected token

Tags: trigger

Error: Compile Error: Unexpected token 'acc.Name'. at line 8 column 56

```apex
trigger duplicaterestriction on Account (before insert) {

    list<Account>acclist = new list<Account>();
   
    
    for(Account Acc : trigger.new){
    
    Acclist=[select id, name from Account where name = acc.name];
    
    if(Acclist.size()>0){
    
        acc.adderror('Record with this name already exist');
      
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are comparing a field with a variable, you need to append : with the query:

```
Acclist=[select id, name from Account where name =: acc.name];
```

But it is not a good practice to have queries within for loop. So, instead, you should try something like this:

```
trigger duplicaterestriction on Account (before insert) {

list<Account>acclist = new list<Account>();
Set<String> setAccountNames = new Set<String>();
Map<String, Account> mapNameToAccounts = new Map<String, Account>();

for(Account Acc : trigger.new) {
    setAccountNames.add(Acc.Name);
}

for(Account acc: [select id, name from Account where name IN: setAccountNames]) {
   mapNameToAccounts.put(acc.Name, acc);
}

for(Account Acc : trigger.new) {
    if(mapNameToAccounts.containsKey(Acc.Name)) {
         Acc.adderror('Record with this name already exist');
    }
}       
}
```

Also, on a separate note Account.Name is not a good parameter to prevent duplicates as there can be some companies with same name. It might be a good idea to brainstorm with your client if they can consider some other criteria for duplicate management.

Comment: N.B. note that this code doesn't check for intra-transaction dups on account name (e.g. a Data Loader or Data Import use case)